# How to store sql query response with dotted lines into a text file?

Tags: mysql, sql, pretty-print

I have a simple question I want be able to store sql query response with dotted lines. So when I hit mysql with command line interface like `mysql -h${sqlhost} -u${sqluser} -p${sqlpass} -e "SELECT * FROM test.employee" > output.txt` I should be able to store structured output in the text file - in linux environment even Windows would do.

[image]

I should be able to store the structured view above into a say 'output.txt' file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--table` switch, as per the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell-output-table-format.html

Comment: can you give one example where to add this switch ?

Comment: I havn't tested it, but you should be able to put it anywhere, e.g.: `mysql --table -h${sqlhost} -u${sqluser} -p${sqlpass} -e "SELECT * FROM test.employee" > output.txt`